# Adding fields to Python AWS Lambda error messages

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Whenever an error is raised in AWS Lambda (either built-in or custom errors), an error message is constructed and returned. The error message has the fields `errorType`, `errorMessage`, and `stackTrace`. I would like to wrap my code in a `try/except` block and add additional fields to before I raise the error, but can't figure out a way to do so. Any idea how this can be done?

```
try:
  some_function()
except Exception as e:
  # Pass additional information/add fields into e
  # Something like e['additional_data'] = 'something'
  raise e
```